# Terraform v0.13 - Check if password or secret provided, use a randomly generated one if not

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform0.12+

I'm working to fine-tune some of my Terraform modules, specifically around the  [google_compute_vpn_tunnel](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_vpn_tunnel), [google_compute_router_interface](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_router_interface), and [google_compute_router_peer](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_router_bgp_peer) resources.  I'd like to make things similar to AWS, where pre-shared keys and tunnel interface IP addresses are randomized by default, but can be overridden by the user (provided they are within a certain range).

The random option is working fine.  For example, to create a 20-character random password, I do this:

```
resource "random_password" "RANDOM_PSK" {
  length           = 20
  special          = false
}
```

But, I only want to use this value if an input variable called **vpn_shared_secret** was not defined.  Seems like this should work:

```
variable "vpn_shared_secret" {
  type      = string
  default   = null
}
locals {
  vpn_shared_secret = try(var.vpn_shared_secret, random_password.RANDOM_PSK.result)
}
resource "google_compute_vpn_tunnel" "VPN_TUNNEL" {
  shared_secret                   = local.vpn_shared_secret
}
```

Instead, it seems to ignore the vpn_shared_secret input variable and just go with the randomly generated one each time.

Is try() the correct way to be doing this?  I'm just now learning Terraform if/else and map statements.

Comment: Your password will end up in plain text in TF state file. I'm not sure if you are fine with that, or you are trying to avoid this?

Comment: I'm assuming the .tfstate file is being stored in a secure location.  I did notice today that Terraform 0.14 and higher has an option for marking data as sensitive

Comment: Sensitive option does not affect plain text in tf state. Its only for terraform plan or apply output.

Comment: That's uhh interesting.  I'd assume the .tfstate state file would be a larger risk for sensitive information since it's stored.  Is there a way to hash or strip sensitive information from .tfstate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the `coalesce()` function?

[The coalesce function takes any number of arguments, and returns the first argument that isn't null or an empty string.](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/coalesce.html)

```
locals {
  vpn_shared_secret = coalesce(var.vpn_shared_secret, random_password.RANDOM_PSK.result)
}
```

Comment: This is definitely the best answer.  I did realize shortly after posting it's also possible with an if/else, but the coalesce is much cleaner.